# Can we carry a Hattori Hanzo sword onboard a plane?

Tags: realism, kill-bill

In the Kill Bill, everyone seems to know that Hanzo swords are made for killing. They are killing tools. Then, how could the Bride carry one so easily on the plane she boards to reach Tokyo?

Also she makes no effort to camouflage it at all, we can see it perched right by the window seat she's seated in.

Is it not an airline safety regulations violation?

Comment: It would be... **if this was the real world** but it's not.

Comment: I agree that it's clearly illegal in reality, but Tarantino is known to ignore reality when it doesn't suit his needs...  See Hitler's death scene in Inglorious Basterds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it not an airline safety regulations violation?

When the Bride departs Tokio, we can see that every seat (in her class) has its own sword holder and other passengers make use of it:

[image: Still from the end of Kill Bill 1, showing sword holders in the plane]

So, not only does the airline allow you to carry a sword to the cabin; it seems to be an everyday occurrence. It’s one of those subtle, but clear confirmations that Kill Bill takes place in a pulp universe – not ours.

Comment: It's obvious that she can carry it in the movie, but I think OP is asking if we can do it in the **real world**.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel if the OP really only cares whether it's possible in the real world, that's really more of a question for Travel, not Movies & TV. I find that the explanation here is more useful because it shows that the rules/expectations within the film are different.

Comment: @Catija Then I guess we should vote to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: Note that this is clearly first class, so not all seats / passengers may be allowed to carry the sword into the plane. As a paid assassin, the bride is probably not poor so she can easily afford the additional fare. And don't forget she initially intended to purchase a Hanzo sword, so she probably has some pocket money left.

Answer (score 5):

The way they present it, no, it doesn't appear to be legal/in concordance with airline regulations - so I chalk that up to creative license of the director.

You **can** bring swords with you *if you check them with your baggage* though. [From here](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/swords):

> **Swords**
>
> **Carry On Baggage**: No
>
> **Checked Baggage**: Yes
>
> Cutting or thrusting weapons, including fencing foils.
>
> Any sharp objects in checked baggage should be sheathed or securely wrapped to prevent injury to baggage handlers and inspectors.

Comment: But then you should definitely check if you are allowed to carry it *outside* the plane as well. You might run into trouble in many EU countries for sure, and [even in Japan](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-in-Japan-to-carry-a-sword-in-public) it seems. Which is not strange, it is a strongly regulated society after all.